# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Компания, на основании изучения потребительской среды (?) предлагает конечный продукт.

Answer (score 3):

Если первая запятая стоит, надо ставить и вторую, иначе запятая будет разделять подлежащее и сказуемое, чего в русском языке быть не может. А вот нужно или нет обособлять "на основании изучения потребительской среды", это решает автор: если это пояснение - обособляем, если нет - не обособляем.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь только обособление двумя запятыми. Это объясняется распространенностью обстоятельственного оборота и его положением между подлежащим и сказуемым. При такой структуре предложения оборот обязательно имеет уточняющий характер.Если предложение переделать: "Компания предлагает конечный продукт на основании изучения потребительской среды", то оборот будет входить в основное сообщение и не будет обособляться.  Правильность постановки знаков препинания можно проверить с помощью интонации - первый вариант без обособления не читается.

ОТВЕТ 2. БЕЗ ОБОСОБЛЕНИЯ СОВСЕМ ПЛОХО. Заданное предложение без обособления будет иметь такую интонацию: Компания на основании изучения потребительской среды (повышении тона, пауза) предлагает конечный продукт. Подлежащее и длинный обстоятельственный оборот приходится объединять в одну фразу – читается конструкция плохо.

С ОБОСОБЛЕНИЕМ НЕМНОГО ЛУЧШЕ, НО ТОЖЕ НЕ ОЧЕНЬ КРАСИВО. Вообще при решении любых задач лучше идти от смысла. Очевидно, автор задумал отнести распространенное обстоятельство на второй план в виде сопутствующего сообщения (это его авторское право). Именно поэтому он ставит оборот между подлежащим и сказуемым, и это правильно. Но предложение, как справедливо было замечено, получилось некрасивым, так как в нем нарушено равновесие объемов – последняя часть предложения слишком коротка. Лучше бы сказать так: Компания, на основании изучения потребительской среды, предлагает свой конечный продукт пользователю.

КАКИМИ ПРАВИЛАМИ Я ПОЛЬЗУЮСЬ. Честно говоря, я правилами не пользуюсь, а применяю метод структурно-интонационного анализа.  Объясняя свое решение, я применяю термины из грамматики и теории интонации, что обычно выглядит достаточно убедительно.

ВОТ ПОПРОБУЮ РЕШИТЬ ВАШУ ЗАДАЧУ. Знаки препинания расставлены верно, да и тематика сообщения вряд ли допустит второй план речи. По сравнению с заданным предложением, здесь другая интонация и другая структура: «И всё же, (пауза, повышение тона) выбрав удобный момент,  (пауза, повышение тона) Хижняк в нарушение всех правил (пауза) пошел на обгон с правой стороны (повышение тона) и поравнялся с «виллисом» (понижение тона). Распространенное обстоятельство  (более короткое) включается в одну синтагму  (произносительную единицу) с подлежащим. Основная интонация строится на выделении однородных сказуемых.

Comment: Почему же так категорично? Если Вы об этом правиле
http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1 , то там слова "обычно обособляются" и внизу приписочка:Однако возможны и иные варианты пунктуационного оформления, обусловленные замыслом автора. Например: И всё же, выбрав удобный момент, Хижняк в нарушение всех правил пошел на обгон с правой стороны и поравнялся с «виллисом»... (В. Богомолов, Момент истины) – невыделение оборота, находящегося между подлежащим и сказуемым . Так что всё от автора зависит.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь дает пишущему право в этом случае обособить обстоятельство.

Answer (score 0):

В таком варианте обособление двумя запятыми, другое дело, предложение построено некрасиво.
Любые два варианта звучали бы лучше: "На основании изучения потребительской среды компания предлагает конечный продукт" или "Компания предлагает конечный продукт на основании изучения потребительской среды"